# What is the difference between NestedScrollView and CustomScrollView?

Tags: dart, flutter

I having hard to understand the difference between NestedScrollView and CustomScrollView?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`CustomScrollView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) - is the most customizable way to build any "scroll" based layouts using `Sliver` objects. `SingleChildScrollView` and `NestedScrollView` are both build on top of it.

[`NestedScrollView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) - is a Wiget provided for a very particular use-case - to put One Scrollable object inside another (in most case - where the directions are not same).

This is what is mentioned in the doc for `NestedScrollView`

> A scrolling view inside of which can be nested other scrolling views, with their scroll positions being intrinsically linked.

The beauty of flutter is that it is open source, you can check the source code to know what is going on under the hood.

Souce Code:

- [CustomScrollView](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/8661d8aecd626f7f57ccbcb735553edc05a2e713/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart#L440)
- [NestedScrollView](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/8661d8aecd626f7f57ccbcb735553edc05a2e713/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart#L366)